# import Tokenizer

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, keras

Я хочу импортировать Tokenizer, но мой PyCharm подчеркивает keras и Tokenizer в импорте ниже красным цветом, однако выполнение кода происходит без ошибок. Не понимаю корректно ли всё отрабатывает

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
```

Правильный ли это импорт? Сам keras установлен. К примеру, следующий импорт отображается корректно

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

Сам PyCharm предлагает стандартные либо импортировать пакет, либо создать функцию в init файле.

В документации видел, что сам preprocessing устарел, но не смог найти никакой информации более. Поэтому вопрос: проблема исключительно в PyCharm или с импортом, возможно с самим методом?

UPD: вру, код выполняется с ошибкой ниже:

```
    from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.preprocessing.text'
```

UPD2: установка keras-preprocessing не помогла

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
```

PyCharm всё ещё подчеркивает красным keras и Tokenizer, однако код отрабатывает без ошибок. Понятия не имею с чем связано такое поведение, но оно работает